# cant render view via renderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi im using RenderAction helper and during rendering i have this error:

> Error executing child request for
>   handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetSearcher()
        {

            SearcherLines sl = new SearcherLines()
            {
                RegionList = db.Region.ToList(),
                CategoryList = db.Category.ToList(),
                SearchValue = null
            };

            return PartialView(sl);
        }
```

ViewModel

```
public class SearcherLines
    {
        public List<Region> RegionList { get; set; }
        public List<Category> CategoryList { get; set; }
        public string SearchValue { get; set; }
    }
```

partialView

```
@model IEnumerable<MasterProject.JobForYou.v3.Models.ViewModels.SearcherLines>

@foreach (var i in Model)
{
  <p>@i.CategoryList</p><br />
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting OutputCache attribute on controller action